# Checking return value for PFFile

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I want to check to see if what the file I am returning is nil.  I currently have the if statement looking like:

```
if (object["profilePicture"] !=  nil){
     //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
```

But I keep getting an error.  How do I check if the file I am getting for a certain user in nil or not.
Thanks!

Comment: What type is `object` of?

Answer (score 0):

just check for the 
PFFile *userImage = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];

then check for the
if(userImage is Equal:[NSNull null]])
{

//perform your actions here

}